# Ensure compatibility of your Kubernetes Engine certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openssl, google-kubernetes-engine

I received an email from Google Cloud[1] about the usage of `X.509 Common Name`, which will be not supported anymore, just the `X.509 Subject Alternative Name (SAN) fields`

1 -

> [Action Required] Ensure compatibility of your Kubernetes Engine certificates before upgrading to version 1.23

How can I discover what kind of SSL certificate my application is using?

Comment: try `openssl x509  -noout -text -in  /path/to/certificate.crt` to get the details about the certificate.

Comment: With current versions of openssl (1.1.1+), you can run `openssl x509 -noout -ext subjectAltName -in /path/to/certificate.crt` - you'll want to make sure that one of the DNS entries matches the expected FQDN of the web hook.

Comment: You can run `openssl x509  -noout -text -in  /path/to/certificate.crt | grep DNS` as well

Comment: I found this
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:mycompany.com, DNS:staging.mycompany.com, DNS:www.mycompany.com this mean that I am running "X.509 Subject Alternative Name (SAN) fields" right?

Answer (score 0):

The Google email is not necessarily referencing your application certificates. It is about certificates used for webhooks inside Kubernetes. This is the announcement from the [upstream release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md#urgent-upgrade-notes):

> Kubernetes is built using golang 1.17. This version of go removes the ability to use a GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0 environment setting to re-enable deprecated legacy behavior of treating the CommonName of X.509 serving certificates as a host name. This behavior has been disabled by default since Kubernetes 1.19 / go 1.15. Serving certificates used by admission webhooks, custom resource conversion webhooks, and aggregated API servers must now include valid Subject Alternative Names. If you are running Kubernetes 1.22 with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0 set, check the apiserver_kube_aggregator_x509_missing_san_total and apiserver_webhooks_x509_missing_san_total metrics for non-zero values to see if the API server is connecting to webhooks or aggregated API servers using certificates that will be considered invalid in Kubernetes 1.23+.

Google also offers a way to check whether this applies to your cluster or not: [Ensuring compatibility of webhook certificates before upgrading to v1.23](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/webhookcompatibility#identifying-affected-clusters)

In case you do not have Google Logging enabled, you can also check the metric `apiserver_kube_aggregator_x509_missing_san_total` via Prometheus or the k8s API server directly as suggested by this [Red Hat Bug Ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2037274).